# How can i hold gridview row selected values into a string in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have gridview control it contains 6 columns when i click 6th column row of gridview i need to selecte that contains columns row text into a string. how can i take here i am taking commandargument is a string and how can i take another column names text

my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Width="950px" CssClass="Grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"  >
                    <Columns>
                          <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Width="950px" CssClass="Grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-ForeColor="White" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SName" HeaderText="SName" />                        
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Size" HeaderText="Size(MB)" />     
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time" />                 

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FileName">  
                                    <ItemTemplate>  
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FileName") %>'  
                                            CommandName="Download" Text='<%# Eval("FileName") %>' />  
                                    </ItemTemplate>  
                                </asp:TemplateField>   
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No." Visible="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>                     
                    </Columns>        
                </asp:GridView>

 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string ID1;
        if (e.CommandName == "Download")
        {
            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
            int rowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
            Label Itemid = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("lblID");
            ID1 = (Itemid).Text;
            Session["ID"] = ID1;
            string filename = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
//here how can i hold another column text
          }
          }
```

Comment: you can add all  controls which you need in rowcommand in Itemtemplate and find them as you did  for lblID  another way is to have a input  and tou can concat all vales as comma separated string and then find that in rowcommand method

Comment: Hi check my answer if it suits your need please mark and like . if you have more question let me know I am happy to help .

Answer (score 0):

I have a easiest way to do this same thing...

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID").ToString() +", "+ Eval("OtherCoulmn").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>

--- hope it helps  

  Also the best way is to do something like this 

 ((MyObject)Container.DataItem).MyProperty where MyObject is the Model which you bind with grid and property which you wan to use in rowcommand its clean .
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow the bellow code sample:

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    Label lblId = gvCipamMember.Rows[gvr.RowIndex].FindControl("lblPersonId") as Label;
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id,Res_Person,Email_ID,Mobile_NO,Cipam_Flag FROM Responsibilty_Master WHERE Id=@Id", con.MyConnection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Convert.ToInt32(lblId.Text.ToString()));
            dt = new DataTable();
            con.MyConnection.Open();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                txtPersonName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Res_Person"].ToString();
                txtEmail.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Email_ID"].ToString();
                txtMobileNo.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Mobile_NO"].ToString();
                if(Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[0]["Cipam_Flag"].ToString())==true)
                {
                    chkbCipamFlag.Checked = true;
                } 
             }
 }
```